# What do the combination of these characters on this ring mean

Tags: translation, meaning

[image]

Could you tell me what my rings says

Answer (score 2):

[image]

It looks like **世界** (World)

My first guess was 壽 because 90% of the time people post this kind of question the answer would end up being it

Comment: Thank you so much that was very fast :) what does the second symbol mean

Comment: 这眼神,犀利的紧~ NB! !

Comment: I meant "my first guess was ____ because 90... What does that symbol mean

Comment: 壽 means 'life span'. The character is commonly used as a symbol for 長壽( longevity)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first half is 世; the second half is 界.